# How to change the arrangement of expose?

Tags: mac, expose

Everytime i open expose the application windows will all be arranged in identical sizes and in line, whereas i see the other mac could arrange the application windows in a wayward manner, some windows are big and some small. Does anyone know how to change this ?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/118424/old-leopard-expose-on-snow-leopard-for-mac

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify Mac OS X  10.5 (Leopard) or 10.6 (Snow Leopard). Snow Leopard tweaked the way Expose worked. With Expose activated, hit Command-1 to sort the applications by window title, Command-2 is a different arrangement (which seems to be the default, but is supposed to be by application name). Command-Tab cycles through applications, showing only the selected application. You can also hit spacebar to zoom the display of the application the mouse if over. If you just hit Tab, it'll cycle through the applications in order.

Comment: I didn't know about the Apple + options or the tab key. Nice answer!

Comment: `Tab` alone cycles in Exposé, `Cmd-Tab` still opens the application switcher.